# Expected Unqualifed-id before 'do'

Tags: c++

I want to write a C++ program that allows a player to play rock paper scissors, but when I try to compile I get the following error message:

```
rps.cpp:50:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'
```

I can't find out what's wrong. My program is pasted below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

char UserChoice() // takes in input
{
    cout << "Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n";
    cout << " Type in the choice you want to make:\n";

    char UserInput = cin.get();

    return UserInput;
}

int ComputerGuess(int SwitchsInput) // generates computer's guess and finds winner
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int ComputerNum = (rand()%3)+1;
    if (ComputerNum == SwitchsInput)
    {
        cout << "It's a tie!\n";
    }
    else if (ComputerNum == 1 && SwitchsInput == 2)
    {
        cout << "You win! \n";
    }
    else if (ComputerNum == 1 && SwitchsInput == 3)
    {
        cout << "You lose!\n";
    }
    else if (ComputerNum == 2 && SwitchsInput == 1)
    {
        cout << "You lose!\n";
    }
    else if (ComputerNum == 2 && SwitchsInput == 3)
    {
        cout << "You win! \n";
    }
    else if (ComputerNum == 3 && SwitchsInput == 1)
    {
        cout << "You win! \n";
    }
    else if (ComputerNum == 3 && SwitchsInput == 2)
    {
        cout << "You lose!\n";
    }
}
do // do loop allows player to play again
{
    int main()
    {
        char Again = 'y';
        UserChoice();
        switch (UserInput) // validates input and converts to integer
        {
            case 'r':
                ComputerGuess(1);
                break;
            case 'R':
                ComputerGuess(1);
                break;
            case 's':
                ComputerGuess(2);
                break;
            case 'S':
                ComputerGuess(2);
                break;
            case 'p':
                ComputerGuess(3);
                break;
            case 'P':
                ComputerGuess(3);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "That is not valid input!\n";
                UserChoice();
                break;      
        }

        cout << "Want to play again? ENter yes if you do.\n";
        Again = cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
} (while Again == 'y' || Again == 'Y')
```

The do loop allows the player to play again without having to start the program.

Comment: BTW, look into c++ enums (prefreably scoped enums), it would make your code much more readable

Comment: Look up `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.  By converting to uppercase or lowercase before the `switch` statement, you can eliminate half of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a loop (or other code that "does something") outside functions. Put the loop inside `main` instead:

```
// Your other function definitions here

int main() {
    char Again = 'y';
    do {
        // Your code
    } (while Again == 'y' || Again == 'Y')
}
```

And btw, in C++ you do not need the `return 0;` in `main`, it is implicit when control flows of the end.

Comment: when I comment out the loop, I get the same message but with the '{' token in line 51.

Comment: @user2532642 The `{` belongs to the loop. I'll try to make it more clear in my answer.